# Javascript - HTML - Image show not working in safari

Tags: javascript, html

i have added loading image, works fine in explorer and chrome. but not working with apple safari in mac nor in iPhone. can't show image

here is code

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function pic1()
    {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "images/waitnew.gif";
    }
 </script>

        <button id="btn_item_search" class="sear-btn" type="submit" onclick="pic1()" ><?php echo SEARCH_TEXT; ?></button>

<img src = "" id = "img"/>
```

thanks for your help.

regards,

Comment: try after deleting cache

Comment: and if you set the src manually, in html, everything works ok? Are you sure you're not getting any others js erros in safari?

Comment: lor no other errors...

Answer (score 0):

It's better that you change the id, to avoid confusion later.

```
<img id = "image"/>
```

Try this :

```
function pic1()
{
  var img=document.getElementById("image");
  img.src=null;
  img.src="images/waitnew.gif"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On animated GIF you can append a random query string in the **url**

```
"your_image_url.gif"+"?a="+Math.random();
```

Answer (score -3):

Set width and height explicitly. 
For example add style tag with your html.

```
style="height:50px; width:50px;"
```

That will do the trick.
PS. Change to appropriate height,width.

Comment: Can you explain why that is? An `img` tag should by default expand to the size the image is.

Comment: It need not. It depends on the browser and the container. 
for example, It wont expand in when we placed image in <td>

Comment: Yep, but OP sets it to an `img` tag.